# SBERT gives same result no matter what

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I have a test script for SBERT:

```
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# 1. Use SBERT to compare two sentences for semantic similarity.
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

input_ids_1 = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute", add_special_tokens=True)).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
input_ids_2 = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my cat is cute", add_special_tokens=True)).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
outputs_1 = model(input_ids_1)
outputs_2 = model(input_ids_2)
last_hidden_states_1 = outputs_1[0]  # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple
last_hidden_states_2 = outputs_2[0]  # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple

# 2. Take SBERT embeddings for both sentences and cluster them.
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(last_hidden_states_1.detach().numpy()[0], last_hidden_states_2.detach().numpy()[0])

# 3. Print the clusters.
print(kmeans.labels_)
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
```

The output is:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[[-0.2281394   0.29968688  0.3390873  ... -0.40648264  0.2930719
   0.41721284]
 [ 0.6079925   0.26097086 -0.3130729  ...  0.03109726 -0.6282735
  -0.19942412]]
```

This happens no matter what the second sentence is. I changed it to "The capital of France is Paris" and it still gave me the same output, so clearly I am not passing/transforming the data correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a couple of tiny modification to sort things out. Please bear in mind in order to cluster sentences you need to catch only the first/last embedding for the sentence. In addition `KMeans` expects to receive a 2D array for clustering.

```
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np 

# 1. Use SBERT to compare two sentences for semantic similarity.
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

input_ids_1 = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute", add_special_tokens=True)).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
input_ids_2 = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("The capital of France is Paris", add_special_tokens=True)).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
outputs_1 = model(input_ids_1)
outputs_2 = model(input_ids_2)
last_hidden_states_1 = outputs_1[0][0, 0, :]  # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple
last_hidden_states_2 = outputs_2[0][0, 0, :]  # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple

# 2. Take SBERT embeddings for both sentences and cluster them.
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit([last_hidden_states_1.detach().numpy(), last_hidden_states_2.detach().numpy()])

# 3. Print the clusters.
print(kmeans.labels_)
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
```

output:

```
[0 1]
[[-0.11437159  0.19371444  0.1249602  ... -0.38269117  0.21065859
   0.54070717]
 [-0.06510071  0.06050608 -0.10048206 ... -0.27256876  0.36847278
   0.57706201]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Would I use the same method if I wanted to do this at scale? (i.e. compare a big text with another big text).

Comment: For scaling up in terms of the number of text samples, there is a batch processing utility. But when it comes to increasing text size some considerations should be kept in mind. Each model can process text up to a certain length but there exist some who are suitable for long text (not gigantic though). You need to find the proper one and modify the settings accordingly.